# Error mapping with CsvHelper using .Constant()

Tags: csvhelper

I'm trying to map a csv file to a POCO class using CsvHelper.  When I try to `csv.GetRecords<Client>()`, I'm getting an error that states:

> Field with name 'InID' does not exist.  You can ignore missing fields by setting MissingFieldFound to null.

However, I'm actually mapping the `InID` property of my class using a Constant:

```
Map(c => c.InID).Constant(true);
```

Based on what I see in the documentation, using `Constant` should not require a field in the CSV file.

Here is my code:

```
public class Client{
  public int Id {get; set;}
  public int FirstName {get; set;}
  public int LastName {get; set;}
  public bool InID {get; set;}
  public bool InMH {get; set;}
}

public class IDMap : ClassMap<Client>
{
    public IDMap(){
        Map(c => c.InID).Constant(true);
        Map(c => c.FirstName).Name("Consumer_First_Name");
        Map(c => c.LastName).Name("Consumer_Last_Name");
    }
}

//In my Controller
List<Client> clients;
using(var csv = new CsvReader(reader))
{
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<IDMap>();
    clients = csv.GetRecords<Client>().ToList();
}
```

I'm not seeing much difference between what I'm doing and the [CsvHelper example](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/configuration/class-maps/constant-value/).

**Note**

I did try adding `csv.Configuration.MissingFieldFound = null` but all that does is cause CsvHelper to skip the `InID` mapping completely rather than populating the property with a constant value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to be a [bug](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1030). The example doesn't work either. You can use `ConvertUsing` instead.

```cs
public class IDMap : ClassMap<Client>
{
    public IDMap()
    {
        Map(c => c.InID).ConvertUsing((IReaderRow row) => true);
        Map(c => c.FirstName).Name("Consumer_First_Name");
        Map(c => c.LastName).Name("Consumer_Last_Name");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a workaround, you can specify that this is actually not a column in the source file by specifying an index of -1.

```
Map(c => c.InID).Index(-1).Constant(true);
```